# How to rename top level site URL in SharePoint server?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I rename the top level site URL website name in SharePoint server 2010?

```
moss10/my/personal/    PS    /SitePages/Home.aspx
```

Website name: `PS`

How change `PS` to `PSSOFT`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5377375/308578

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I only have access to a German SharePoint installation. Hopefully the screenshots guide you in the right direction:

1. Go to the website settings:
   [image]
2. Edit title, description and icon:
   [image]
3. Finally, change the name part of the URL:
   [image]

Comment: thanks, +1 but is this which that he didn't understand?

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi: What do you mean?